# capacitor uF values question

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor

Can I put a bunch of 220 uF caps together to get a higher uF value? or is it best to replace with the same value of cap.

Comment: Yes, put them in parallel. Why do you need higher capacitance? We can provide better advice with more context.

Comment: yes, that's often cheaper and in fact, they work better for most applications since the ESR divides by _n_.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can put a bunch of 220uF caps in PARALLEL to get a higher value of capacitance.  You also have to pay attention to the voltage rating of the caps, polarity, and potentially things like the ESR, dielectric, and self resonant frequency, depending on the application.

Some ceramic capacitors in particular will derate with applied DC bias, so it's important to understand not only the value of capacitance, but the characteristics of the cap as well.

So if chosen correctly according to the requirements of the application, it's possible.

Comment: they are all electrolytic caps is that gonna be a problem?

Comment: @bigstupidyt If the voltage ratings are OK, and you watch the polarity chances are you will be fine.  There are some applications though where the ESR of the caps is important, and without knowing the details it's impossible to say for sure if it will work.

Comment: You also obviously multiply the leakage current and have the potential advantage of fewer part types on your BOM.  Say you use 1 somewhere and 2 elsewhere, instead of ordering 250,000 of one and 250,000 of the other, you can order 750,000 of one and hopefully get a better price point.  If you can do this all over a board, the bulk savings can be quite significant.